# Why Sportsmanship badge was not awarded?

Tags: discussion, sportsmanship-badge

I voted on more than 100 competing answers. Even then I have not received `Sportsmanship` badge.
This is my profile [Sachin Mhetre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312147/sachin-mhetre). 
My account was merged with another account. Is this a reason for not getting sporsmanship badge?

Comment: Sportsmanship sounds like one hell of a query and probably isn't executed that frequently.

Answer (score 14):

How long have you waited?

There is a job that runs every now and then and hands out badges. Wait for it. Should be a day-ish.

Also, are you sure they were *competing* answers? By competing, we mean that they were answers to a question which you have also have **an upvoted answer** (I'm telling you this since we had a recent meta-post where someone was confused on this)

Anyway, how did you know that there are 100? Did you count? (there's no competing vote metric offered by the system)

Comment: The key is that your answer has to be upvoted as well

Comment: @Chris whoops, forgot to mention. Thanks!

Comment: Its been more than 2-3 weeks. And also I counted upvotes on answers, they are more than 100.

Comment: @sachin your answers need upvotes as well.

Answer (score 7):

You only have 28 answers, and only 18 of those have any up-votes.

Have you really voted for 100 answers on those 18 questions?

Are there even 100 competing answers to vote for?

Comment: I think I am getting wrong meaning about competing answers. I was thinking that **Competing answer means, other answers on the question which you have also answered.**

Comment: Was I wrong? Whats the competing answers means?

Comment: @SachinMhetre - A competing answer is another answer to a question you have answered.

Comment: So I was right... But does this mean that, my answers also have upvotes?

Comment: @SachinMhetre - yes your answers must be upvoted as well

Comment: Ohhhh... Sorry, I didnt know about that. Now I'll keep it in mind. Thanks for correcting my knowledge.

Comment: This is little off topic, but is it a good habit to write name(`@xxx`) in comment?

Comment: @SachinMhetre - the `@name` directs the comment at that person so they get notified in their inbox.