# Winter Bash hats delay

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

Is there a delay before getting your [Winter Bash](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/welcome-to-winter-bash-2012/) hats once you meet the requirements to get them?

I accepted by clicking `I Love Hats` and logged in. Meanwhile, I meet the requirements for some hats, but I can't see them anywhere. (They are still grayed out in the Winter Bash page.)

It obviously started, because I can see users collecting them already (not just the December 16th 2012 one).

[image]

---

Let's take this present post as an example. It was posted 45 minutes ago, and I got an upvote. I meet the requirements for the `Constantipolitan Hat`. But I still don't have it. I should have earned a few other hats before posting this question, and I don't have them either.

Is it just a delay or a real problem?

Comment: +1, Even I think there is a delay in getting the hats. Even though I got a few hats already(a few related to review), I have also met the requirements for some other hats but I haven't yet got any hats for them.

Comment: @ACB did you get your other hats ?

Comment: No, nothing after getting those.

Comment: I'm having the opposite problem. I just got a "Tis the season" hat, which is supposed to be for commenting or voting on Dec 25. It's currently about Dec 24 18:20 UTC. I think I noticed a similar thing for the "I feel fine" hat. What timezone is being used to decide the day that activity occurs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, hats are [badges you can wear](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95/do-we-want-hats#comment1119_96), so I guess they *behave* like badges. In that, I mean that each hat, in the back end, has a serverside script which runs periodically, [just like badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130402/178438). The heavier scripts probably are run less often. Some badges take a day to award--I don't think that will be the case here, but it's similar.

Answer (score 23):

So I think you're a little confused because of the **L'Chaim** hat.

The L'Chaim hat is the ***only*** hat being awarded retroactively. We wanted a way to celebrate Hannukah, but we couldn't fit this event inside the actual Channukah dates. So, we opted to retroactively award hats in *this instance alone*.

All other hats must be earned by actions performed between **00:00 UTC 19 December 2012** and **23:59 UTC 4 January 2013**. Happy hat-hunting!

Comment: I get your point. Although check my question, I added a picture. How could the other badges be awarded

Comment: For the upvote-type ones, do they have to reach, say, 10 upvotes during the period or would a post that was already at +9 that gets another upvote still qualify?

Comment: oh UTC. my bad it's 1 a.m I think. so I guess I have a delay for my upcoming hats.. ?

Comment: @animuson It should be that these are awarded for posts that were made after 19 December 2012 00:00 UTC

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Nope, shouldn't be much of a delay. Though it could be cacheing. It's always cacheing.

Comment: Probably. You see, I just posted on meta (which is a hat too) and got an upvote so I meet the requirements 15 min ago.

Comment: Ah ha. Give it another 15 minutes or so; if you still don't have a hat, then there might be an error.

Comment: @Aarthi I guess I should have it by now no ?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Well, MSO doesn't have a meta, so no one can get any of the "meta" hats on this site. :( You could get it on SO, though!

Comment: @Aarthi .. I'm on the SO meta right ? SO do have a meta and i'm on it. Therefor, I posted on the meta. Anyway that's not the point I still didn't get any on SO either.

Comment: @Aarthi I just got one. (on meta tough) I guess there is only a big delay

Comment: @Aarthi: well, it's been days for me now since I earned my first hat, and my avatar is still not showing any... On any of the sites (stackoverflow, ux, programmers). Disappointed.

Comment: @MarjanVenema That is super weird! Are you blocking scripts? Are you logged into winterba.sh? Are you running a proxy?

Comment: @Aarthi: no, yes, no. Using Google Chrome, even checked with my pet hate IE.

Comment: @MarjanVenema I think you need to make a new meta post about this -- sounds like you need some focused support for this issue!

Comment: @Aarthi: ok thanks, will do.

Answer (score 3):

You only get hats that you earn after the Winter Bash started.

Comment: I get that but it's started now right ? I see hats on a few profiles. There is even a leaderboard. And I accomplished some actions meanwhile that should have been giving me a hat AFTER in clicked on the I love hats button to get started.

Comment: I think most of the hats one the leaderboard are from the one retroactive hat, L'chaim. Try just giving it some time to award the hats you earned.

Comment: You can look at the picture I added in my question. There are many hats. Though I think you're right with the delay i'll have to wait.