# How much time does it take to award any hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

See this description of `My Dear Watson`:

> ### My Dear Watson
>
> edit a post

Have a look at [my revision history.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187824/hims056?tab=activity&sort=revisions) I have already edited a post more than 1 hour ago. But still I am not awarded this hat on Meta.

So how much time does it take to award any hat?

Comment: It seems to be inconsistent.

Comment: I haven't gotten my hat for editing a post yet, but I got the one for *improving* a post (a long time ago at that), which requires editing, so yes, I'm a bit confused on that one.

Comment: @animuson - Exactly. I faced the same issue.

Comment: PS: While asking this question I earned that hat on Stack Overflow.

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159136/169404)

Comment: I have exactly the same question right now. The bowler is the best hat, in my opinion. Well, tied with the Waldo hat.

Comment: Took me an hourish for "my dear Watson" as well. My guess: there are server scripts which run at various time intervals, depending on the load each script causes. Like badges.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - To clear our confusion see [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159209/187824)

Comment: No no no. It's not a duplicate. See [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159209/187824).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per  [Emmett ♦'s comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159196/how-much-time-does-it-take-to-award-any-hat#comment461030_159199)

He has updated the description of [My Dear Watson](http://winterba.sh/my-dear-watson)

> make 5 edits

So, actually we have to edit at least 5 post to earn this hat.
That's why I and [other users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159196/how-much-time-does-it-take-to-award-any-hat#comment461000_159196) were not awarded that hat because we edited less than 5 posts at that time.

Comment: Well, that's a pretty big change! It's all just for fun, though; no harm done.

Answer (score 8):

For the six or so hats I've gotten so far... Five to ten minutes for each hat, once the achievement is unlocked.

Comment: Yes. I too. But as you can see that particular hat is not awarded to me yet. Also [see animuson's comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159196/how-much-time-does-it-take-to-award-any-hat#comment461000_159196)

Comment: This is correct-- hats are awarded every 5 minutes, but then as a result of caching, it may take another few minutes to see it on the leaderboard or in your Winter Bash inbox.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be very inconsistent. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159136/169404) question may be of help (they suggest it could be caching)

Personally, it has taken from 5 minutes to over an hour and still no hat for making an edit (same problem as you)!

Comment: Oops, [My Dear Watson](http://winterba.sh/my-dear-watson) is actually awarded for *5* edits -- I just updated the hat description to reflect this.