# When are hats rewarded?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Winter Bash hats delay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159136/winter-bash-hats-delay)

I think I qualify for some hats which have not yet been rewarded.  Are hats supposed to come instantaneously upon qualification, or is there a certain time when your hats are re-evaluated?

Comment: Duplicate? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159136/169404

Comment: @aus - Definitely. Also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159196/how-much-time-does-it-take-to-award-any-hat).

Comment: @Lix Yep, I already included that link in my answer :p

Answer (score 1):

Most hats are awarded instantaneously. Check every 5-30 minutes, as some scripts run less frequently than others. In my experience, the meta-to-main hats are on the longest delay.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159136/169404) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159196/169404).

Robert Harvey said 5 to 10 minutes per hat for him. I have noticed that it sometimes takes 30 minutes for me but that may be caching.

Answer (score 0):

The hat script (close relative to the badge script), is not instantaneous as you have noticed. It takes 5-10 minute to show up. By the time you are finished reading this you'll probably already have your new head-gear*.

> ***** [head-gear does not necessarily have to go on your head](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159264/this-isnt-a-hat-this-is-a-glasses)