# Can a hat be lost if its criteria no longer applies?

Tags: support, winter-bash

Several of the winterbash hats have criteria that are "non-binding," for example "Witticism" requires 5 upvoted questions.

If such a criteria no longer applies, such as an upvoted question or answer getting downvoted later and no longer qualifying for a hat, will the user keep the affected hat or will it no longer be available?

Comment: While the dupe is not direct, it does include this part under "We don't (usually) take away hats once they're awarded"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You do **not** lose hats.

I had an answer upvoted and then later downvoted but I kept my hat.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip. I was tempted to delete this question to answer my question, but now I don't have to. :)

Comment: Yep, hats are like badges (though temporary) - once you gain one you can't really lose it.

Answer (score 6):

Why would it? Considering that non-tag badges aren't even revoked for things like this and that the hats will only exist for a couple weeks, do you really think they built processes to *revoke* hats, of all things?

Comment: "...do you really think they built processes to revoke hats..." Hehe, no. But neither of us knows the actual process (right?), so that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 4):

It's all for celebration:

> Stack Exchange invites you to celebrate the end of a great year…

So, in my humble opinion, they won't be taking your cheers and laughter away!

Comment: Unless it gives *them* cheers and laughters! :O

Answer (score 3):

I doubt it. Like I mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159202/178438), hats are badges you can wear, and they probably behave like badges. So you probably get to keep them.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would not and behave like badge .. we dont loose badge  on deleted question or answer

for example Hafizul Amri has [great question badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/22/great-question?userid=458036) even after [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891873/how-does-facebook-achieve-good-performance) got deleted

Comment: I've always wondered about that. Thanks for the example. :)

Comment: @tenterhook yours welcome