# Can I lose hats?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Can a hat be lost if its criteria no longer applies?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159216/can-a-hat-be-lost-if-its-criteria-no-longer-applies)

I just earned the pirate hat for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993165/how-to-remove-html-li-bullets-from-codebehind/13993181#13993181).

If the OP comes back and changes his mind to accept my answer, do I still keep the hat?

## My precious hats!

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159216/169404

Comment: You did this for the bow tie didn't you...

Comment: @AustinHenley lol I had that already.

Comment: I genuinely did not know this was asked already.

Comment: Oh ok :p Continue with your hat hunt!

Comment: you can lose the game

Comment: When you upvote a post in the review queue without reading it you lose all of your hats.

Comment: @Servy **OH NO!!!**  I'll lose my lead!

Comment: How dare you say '[My precious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gollum)' and allude to [hairy hobbits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobbit) when we're dealing with this [hairy Punyon outbreak](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159782/the-mysterious-epic-punyon-beard)? You _insensitive_ clod!

Comment: Ahhh I forgot to congratulate @JasonPunyon !! How could I forget about him?!

Comment: @TinyTimPost ^_^

Comment: That's better. We'll overlook this for now, it won't go down on your permanent record. BTW, Congrats @JasonPunyon :)

Answer (score 3):

Hats are just like badges; once earned you don't lose them even when the criteria are no longer met.

Answer (score 2):

To quote my self from [Can a hat be lost if its criteria no longer applies?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159216/169404) :

> You do **not** lose hats.
>
> I had an answer upvoted and then later downvoted but I kept my hat.