# Am I eligible for hats if I join a Stack Exchange site after the start of Winter-Bash?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

The question pretty much tells it all.

I joined [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/116985/tintinmj) today and I'm not seeing any hats in my profile. So joining any SE site after Winter-Bash starts doesn't grant me hats? I see that there may be a [delay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159136/winter-bash-hats-delay). Is this the case?

Comment: Isn't that a `Link to the past` cap? Or do you naturally have Spock-ears ? ;-)

Comment: @StuartC `link to the past`.

Comment: The existence of the "Hello, World" (very first post, scoring 1+) hat would suggest that new members are more than welcome to WinterBash.

Comment: He's saying the hats(and anything hat-related) don't show up on his Math.SE profile, but it's only been about 30 minutes since joining as of now. Might have to wait it out. I tried joining myself and see the same issue.

Comment: @GenericHolidayName so I'm victim of dealay-rious?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just joined Math.SE to test this out. No hat, no hat-link in my profile.

To make the hat appear on your profile, you can go to the hat page from one of your *hat-enabled* profiles, and click the "Wear Hat" button again. After doing this, my Johnny Three Hats showed up on Math. After a minute or two and another refresh, the hat link showed up as well.

Comment: Please make hats faster [feature-request] [winterbash-2014]

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if it would've appeared any time soon if I hadn't done a forced "Wear Hat". I didn't wait around to find out, maybe someone else can.

Comment: Yup, this is the answer. You just need to force Winter Bash to re-count your hat-enabled sites by triggering a network-wide Wear Hat (or Remove Hat). This isn't an ideal setup, but we're only doing this for a few weeks, so it's what we'll live with.

Comment: Yeah, so basically, you get out of the car and then get back in, and it works.

Answer (score 6):

> So joining any SE site after Winter-Bash starts doesn't grants me hats?

It does. If you actually *earn* a hat on the site you just joined, that will also cause your account list to be refreshed. To *force* the update manually before you've earned any hats there, the [generic holiday answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212900/115866) is correct.